# GHC panic on fresh Yesod framework

Tags: haskell, yesod

I'm trying to start going through the book / tutorial for Yesod, but I've hit a problem relatively early. I'm able to successfully install `yesod-platform` and `yesod-bin`, but whenever I create a framework using `yesod init` with a SQL database (tried with both postgres and SQLite), I receive the following error when `cabal install`-ing said framework.

```
Loading package persistent-sqlite-1.2.1 ... ghc.exe: 
Unknown PEi386 section name `.drectve' (while processing: 
C:\SSol\yesod\one\.cabal-sandbox\i386-windows-ghc-7.6.3\
persistent-sqlite-1.2.1\libHSpersistent-sqlite-1.2.1.a) ghc.exe: 
panic! (the 'impossible' happened)  
(GHC version 7.6.3 for i386-unknown-mingw32):         loadArchive
"C:\\SSol\\yesod\\one\\.cabal-sandbox\\i386-windows-ghc-7.6.3\\
persistent-sqlite-1.2.1\\libHSpersistent-sqlite-1.2.1.a": failed
```

A similar error occurs when using a different SQL database, with the applicable persistent package.

However, when building a framework with no database, it installs without a hitch.

I'm using cabal-install native sandboxing on cabal-install version 1.18.03 (though I had the same issue with 1.18.02). I've tried a few fresh installs, and with a clean package cache, all with the same result.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This may not at all be relevant, but I've had similar kinds of bugs with lots of different packages on my Linux system since using cabal-install 1.18. One thing that worked for me was (1) deleting the entirety of my ~/.ghc folder and (2) reverting to cabal-install 1.16.

Comment: I'm actually now running into an error running yesod devel on the no-DB framework. GHC crashes and devel throws the error:
Exit code: ExitFailure (-1073741819)
I've no idea if they're related. 

If you think it's worthwhile, I guess I'll try starting over in a totally fresh environment. I'll probably just build a VM; do you recommend linux over win specifically? If so, is any flavor more supported than another?

Thanks, both for your answer now, and for all your work on Yesod.

Comment: I personally develop on Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit, so that's probably the most well tested combination. That's also what the FP Complete servers run on, so there's a lot of testing there as well. Things should work fine on Windows in general (I just did a build there yesterday), but there's obviously some kind of a bug here. I'd probably still recommend trying to wipe out your package database and trying again before resorting to a VM.

Comment: I had wiped out the package database as one of my troubleshooting steps before posting; sorry, I thought I had mentioned that in my original post. I just tried installing on Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit, but got caught up very quickly in cabal hell (conflict in warp). (As an aside, the instructions in 1.2.2.1 after you "lay the foundation" assume you have cabal 1.18 installed; they include "cabal sandbox init"). I guess I'll go back to trying to get it to work with sandboxes. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be an instance of [this](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/7056) bug in `ghc`. It should be [fixed](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/changeset/24b791f9618e263d0a972be0ea4883d8f582d0fe/ghc) in `HEAD`.

How did you install `ghc`? AFAIK prebuilt package contains known-to-work `gcc` version. Did you compiled `ghc` from sources? If yes, then try the [prebuilt](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/download_ghc_7_6_3#windows) package.

Comment: I used the prebuilt ghc in the HP (2013.2.0.0). I've tinkered with cabal since then, but not ghc itself. I'll try reinstalling ghc to see what happens; if that doesn't work, I'll give HEAD a shot. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is a bug of `Cabal`.

Workaround: uncomment the line library-for-ghci: True in %APPDATA%\cabal\config. And then `cabal install  persistent-sqlite --reinstall`

You can find more discuss [here](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/1589)